# Flight to Taiwan covid test

Tags: covid-19

I have a question regarding corona test. I read governmental website for Taiwan. Can anybody clarifies me about the possible positive result for corona and flight? It is written in the taiwan governmental website that in case someone has positive result he can wait 7 days and then flight without pcr test. I attach a photo but please help me about it.
Is it right?

[https://www.cdc.gov.tw/En/Category/QAPage/SbkmnM5v0OwdDMjJ2tI_xw#:~:text=1.Travelers%20must%20present%20a,to%20the%20flight%20schedule%20time](https://www.cdc.gov.tw/En/Category/QAPage/SbkmnM5v0OwdDMjJ2tI_xw#:%7E:text=1.Travelers%20must%20present%20a,to%20the%20flight%20schedule%20time).

Answer (score 4):

You would like the [Taiwan covid page](https://www.cdc.gov.tw/En/Category/QAPage/SbkmnM5v0OwdDMjJ2tI_xw#:%7E:text=1.Travelers%20must%20present%20a,to%20the%20flight%20schedule%20time) to mean that a traveler who tests positive can wait 7 days and then enter Taiwan without a PCR test. The page does not say that. The reasonable meaning of these words does not say that.

The page's wording is:

- Passengers tested **positive** for COVID-19 abroad must defer their flights to Taiwan for **> 7** days from the specimen collection date. *(emphasis in original)*

The reasonable construction of this wording is that having been unable to enter because of a positive test, the clock is merely reset. There is no statement that receiving a positive test result means no further testing is required; indeed, given Taiwan's goal of restricting entry to those who present a negative test, this would be irrational.

Thus, to enter Taiwan, all travelers must meet the original Taiwan Covid entry requirements, i.e., show a negative Covid test issued within two days before the scheduled flight. Taiwan immigration authorities and airlines will apply the "negative test required" to all travelers, including those who have previously tested positive.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the only difference is if positive then after 7 days even anti body test is Ok if pcr is not available.

Comment: So, consider I have flight on 6 august 3 pm and it is written the test 2 days before flight. So how long does it take to get the result? I just could change or cancel the flight 24 hours maximum before flight so I need to know the result before that timrm on the other hand we have 2 days before flight to do the test? What should I do? How restrict is that two days? Can I ask the center to enter the date of test as when I get the result date not the test date?

Comment: @AhmadTurani You write "...if positive then after 7 days even anti body test is Ok if pcr is not available." This is not correct. The Taiwan page says "A **negative PCR test** report issued within 2 days prior to scheduled flight time.** Nothing is said about substituting or using an antibody test. Thus, the traveler must present a negative PCR test in order to be admitted to Taiwan.

Comment: @AhmadTurani Scheduling can be difficult. The requirements are that the traveler have a PCR report, that the report is negative, and that the report was issued 2 days before scheduled flight time. "Scheduled flight time" must mean departure time, as one can't receive a test report issued while one is flying. Thus, you must take a PCR test from a provider who promises to issue the report to you within 2 days of the departure of your flight to Taiwan.

Comment: 2.Travelers who have been diagnosed with COVID-19 in the last 90 days must present their positive test result or certificate of diagnosis from the 7 to 90 days prior to their flight schedule time and proof (1) a negative result from a rapid antigen test, (2) a negative result from a PCR test, or (3) a positive result with a CT value ≥30 from a PCR test taken within the two days prior to their flight schedule time.   Obviously written after 7 days of positive test what you can do. PCR is not a must in that case. You can do three different ways.

Comment: Ok then if my flight is 6 august 3 pm then I will do the test 4 august morning that I can know the result at least more than 24 hours before flight that I can cancel or change the flight.

Comment: What is the source of your comment that begins "2.Travelers..." ?

Comment: What source. I already gave the source. Look at the link I gave!

Comment: The link you provided is the main page. There are numerous pages under and linked to that page. I'm not going to search them all. Please provide a link to the page _that contains the language you quote_.

Comment: It is a faq page first question in faq look you can find easily since the link is same. I provided photo as an answer. Look down

Comment: Thank you. The text addresses travelers _who have been diagnosed with covid_, not those who have merely tested positive. In some places (the first page), the immigration authorities use the word "tested." In other places (this FAQ), they use the word "diagnosed." To me, this indicates the authorities understand "test" and "diagnose" as different things. My view is that if you were diagnosed, then this FAQ wording applies to you; if you were only tested, then it does not apply.